# What does this /etc/sudoers syntax mean?

Tags: sudo

Can someone translate the following text from an `/etc/sudoers` file to readable English for me? I'm wondering specifically what `- orpkale` means.

```
557149 ALL =(root) /bin/su - orpkale
```

Comment: Just a comment, its `/etc/sudoers` not `etc/sudoers`. And I think it means it has something to do with who or what has permissions to root. And `/bin/sh` is the shell for that use. Preferably, I use `/bin/bash`. Hope this helps anyways.

Comment: See http://toroid.org/sudoers-syntax

Answer (score 0):

It means that user `557149` is allowed to start a login shell as user `orpkale`. From `man su`:

```
-, -l, --login
    Provide an environment similar to what the user would expect had
    the user logged in directly.

    When - is used, it must be specified before any username. For
    portability it is recommended to use it as last option, before any
    username. The other forms (-l and --login) do not have this
    restriction.
```

Comment: I would say `UID` and not `user 557159`. Right?

Comment: @NerdOfCode hmm... actually I'm not sure; I *thought* that UIDs had to be prefixed with `#` within `/etc/sudoers`? OTOH I'm not sure if numeric usernames are allowed.

Comment: Ah. Alright, you probably know more than me @steeldriver.